# Set dataframe indexes to represent multiple datetime?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
             D         3D          W         2W          M
0   2023-03-20        NaT 2023-03-20        NaT        NaT
1   2023-03-17        NaT        NaT        NaT        NaT
2   2023-03-16 2023-03-16        NaT        NaT        NaT
3   2023-03-15        NaT        NaT        NaT        NaT
4   2023-03-14        NaT        NaT        NaT        NaT
5   2023-03-13 2023-03-13 2023-03-13 2023-03-13        NaT
6   2023-03-10        NaT        NaT        NaT        NaT
7   2023-03-09        NaT        NaT        NaT        NaT
8   2023-03-08 2023-03-08        NaT        NaT        NaT
9   2023-03-07        NaT        NaT        NaT        NaT
10  2023-03-06        NaT 2023-03-06        NaT        NaT
11  2023-03-03 2023-03-03        NaT        NaT        NaT
12  2023-03-02        NaT        NaT        NaT        NaT
13  2023-03-01        NaT        NaT        NaT 2023-03-01
14  2023-02-28 2023-02-28        NaT        NaT        NaT
15  2023-02-27        NaT 2023-02-27 2023-02-27        NaT
```

Hi.

Whenever I query a date under column 'D' it brings me a unique dataframe from collection D for the selected date.

Dates under 3D, W, 2W, M also brings unique dataframes from different collections.

However for instance querying date '2023-03-10' for collection returns empty for 3D,W,2W,M.

But date '2023-03-01' of collection 'M' also applies for date '2023-03-10',
date '2023-02-27' of collection 2W is also effective for '2023-03-10' etc.

So whenever I query date '2023-03-10' of collection 'D', i also want to return dataframes from:

3D-2023-03-08, W-2023-03-06, 2W-2022-02-27 and M-2023-03-01.

This has to be the only way to achieve this as i can't modify or reproduce dates on the database.
I'm out of solutions for this. Is a there logic for this in Pandas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need backfilling missing values by next values by [`DataFrame.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html):

```
#for all columns without first
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].bfill()
```

---

```
#for all columns without D
df.update(df.drop('D', axis=1).bfill())
```

Comment: This fulfills my question. However this is what i need. I asked an additional question. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75816920/dynamic-indexing-return-second-or-first-valid-index-based-on-condition